# pagination / accessing more than 100 tweets using tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I have come up with the following code which iterates over a bunch of dates and streams tweets using twitters full_archive_search. Note that I am using the free sandbox version to access the past tweets, which allows 50 requests per month. The issue I am having is that I want to access more than 100 tweets per day. (The search only gives 100 tweets/results from the first page only, How do I access the second page and so on?) After referring the tweepy documentation I have a feeling that this can be controlled with the `next` parameter. But I have no clue how to use it.

```
import tweepy as tw
from datetime import date,timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relative delta

# Create a range of dates 
start_date = date(2020,1,1)
end_date = date(2020,1,31)
date_range = [start_date + timedelta(days = i) for i in range(relativedelta(end_date,start_date).days)]
dates_str =[i.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M') for i in date_range]

# Autenticate twitter
auth = tw.OauthHandler(
    consumer_key = ???
    consumer_secret = ???
)
api = tw.API(auth)

df_list = []

# Iterate over each date and extract maximum of 100 tweets per date. How do I increase this number?
for dt_idx, dt in enumerate(date_str):
    if dt_idx < len(dates_str) - 1:
        twObj = api,search_full_archive(
            environment_name = ???,
            query = '#Taal',
            fromDate = dates_str[dt_idx],
            toDate = dates_str[dt_idx + 1],
        )
        
        #iterate over the tweet object and save tweet text
        tweet_list = []
        for tweet in twObj:
            tweet_list.append(tweet.text)

        #append the tweet_list to df_list
        df_list.append(tweet_list)
```

I am wondering how to add the `next` parameter inside the tweet object to extract more than 100 tweets per date? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is use user_timeline for that, you will also run into the same issue of having to deal with the pagination. To solve that one, you use ".Cursor"

So how you would run it in your code:

```
tweet_list = []
for tweet in twObj:
    tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name = "", count = 200, tweet_mode 
    = 'extended').items
```

Here is the function I personally used, I prefer to set the function to run just once, and then have it loop when I call on it. I think it's cleaner and you can check for errors without having to let the function loop.

```
def extract_tweets(userid):
    all_tweets = []
    tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,screen_name = userid, 
                            count = 200, 
                            tweet_mode = 'extended').items()
```

Let me know if you run into any errors